# detached entity passed to persist - on findByMethod

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, jpa, spring-data-jpa, transactions

I understand the error message and i know how to solve it, but i want to know why it occurs in this specific place especially on a find method.
I created a mini example for this.

I have three entitys:

```
@Entity
data class Animal(
    var name: String,
    @ManyToOne(cascade = [CascadeType.ALL]) val zoo: Zoo) {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    var id: Int = -1
}

@Entity
data class Zoo(
    var city: String,
    @OneToMany(cascade = [CascadeType.ALL]) val employee: MutableList<Person>) {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    var id: Int = -1
}

@Entity
data class Person(var age: Int) {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    var id: Int = -1
}
```

Service:

```
   @Transactional
    fun save(name:String, city: String){
        repo.findByZooCity(city).ifPresent {
            it.zoo.employee.add(Person(22))
        }
        repo.findByZooCity("OTHER STRING!!!!").ifPresent { println("FOUND!") }
        repo.save(Animal(name, Zoo(city, mutableListOf(Person(33)))))
    }
```

Repo:

```
interface AnimalRep: JpaRepository<Animal, Int>{

    fun findByZooCity(name: String): Optional<Animal>
}
```

Call:

```
  animalService.save("Zoo1", "Animal1")
  animalService.save("Zoo1", "Animal1")
```

Exception:
On the second call i get a "detached entity passed to persist: com.example.Person" on `repo.findByZooCity("OTHER STRING!!!!")`. I know this happens because i add a "detached" person before. But WHY it occurs on a findBy? (Even its not in results?)

Is there some dirty check?

Thank you for your time and help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This behavior depends on [FlushMode](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/FlushMode.html) of [EntityManager](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html).

The `FlushMode` defines when new entities and your changes on existing ones get written to the database, in other words, defines when `flush()` operation is performing.

> The flush process synchronizes database state with session state by
> detecting state changes and executing SQL statements.

The JPA specification defines the [FlushModeType.AUTO](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/FlushMode.html#AUTO) as the default flush mode. It flushes the persistence context in next situations:

- before the transaction gets committed
- before executing a query that uses any database table for which your persistence context contains any pending changes.

According to [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/FlushMode.html#AUTO):

> AUTO
>
> The Session is sometimes flushed before query execution in order to
> ensure that queries never return stale state. This is the default
> flush mode.

**Summary:**

So in your example, we have default `FlushMode.AUTO`, during the query execution framework performs `flush()` operation, this is the reason.

`FlushMode.AUTO` is fixing consistency issues on a query basis, but on other hand can lead to unpredictable flush operations and as result performance problems in the case of huge services. I recommend to change `FlushMode` to `COMMIT`, when you do not need to resolve consistency issues. The [FlushModeType.COMMIT](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/FlushMode.html#COMMIT) requires a flush before committing the transaction but doesn’t define what needs to happen before executing a query.  Executing any query doesn’t flush any pending changes.

**Changing `FlushMode`:**

**1. Globally for server add to properties**

```
spring.jpa.properties.org.hibernate.flushMode=COMMIT
```

**2. Set for specific query**

```java
Query quey = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT * from Foo");
quey.setFlushMode(FlushModeType.COMMIT);
```

**3. Set for `Session`**

Inject `EntityManager` into your service.

```kotlin
   @Transactional
    fun save(name:String, city: String){
        entityManager.setFlushMode(FlushModeType.COMMIT)
        ...
    }
```

Detailed described at [How does AUTO flush strategy work in JPA and Hibernate](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-does-the-auto-flush-work-in-jpa-and-hibernate/)

Comment: Thank you, that was the part i missed :)